# macos の TMPDIR に作成したファイル・ディレクトリはいつ削除される？

Tags: macos

macos は、 `TMPDIR` の環境変数から一時ファイル用フォルダを取得できます。

## 質問

ここに作成したファイルやディレクトリはいつ削除されますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$TMPDIR` = `/var/folders` 以下のディレクトリということであれば、`dirhelper`というプロセスが
**3日前より古いファイル**を削除対象としているようです。

参考:
[macOSの$TMPDIR以下のファイルが部分的に削除された理由 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/hnw/items/7a301eb07475da228b36)
[tmuxのunixドメインソケットを消している犯人を特定したい - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/21222)